# Split a Flux into two based on a condition without GroupBy

Tags: java, project-reactor

For a given stream of data:

```
Flux<Integer> evenFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
                         .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)

Flux<Integer> oddFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
                         .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
```

Instead of this how can I split using a single pipeline?
All filtered elements to one `Flux` and discarded elements to another `Flux`. Using `onDiscardHook` or something?

Note: I need to do a `repeat()` operation on the new `Flux`. Was not able to perform repeat on `GroupedFlux`.

Comment: groupBy() is likely to be your best bet here. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 1):

It depends, you have two options here:

Option 1 is to create two new pipelines from hot input source:

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> input = Flux.range(1,7).publish();

//Pipeline 1
input.filter(i -> i % 2== 0)
    .subscribe(e -> System.out.println("Even stream value: " + e));

//Pipeline 2
input.filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
    .subscribe(o -> System.out.println("Odd stream value: " + o));

input.connect();
```

Option 2 is to process results in a single subscriber, like grouping by:

```
Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    .subscribe(n -> {
      if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Even stream value: " + n);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Odd stream value: " + n);
      }
    });
```

Comment: For option 1 and 2, please check if it compiles. I got compile error with io.projectreactor version 3.4.12

Comment: Yes, @samabcde it compiles now...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Michael Berry, using [`groupBy`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-) is one of the solution.
We can group using `i % 2` which return a `Flux<GroupedFlux>`, then we can use [`GroupedFlux#key()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/GroupedFlux.html#key--) to distinguish odd or even group.

```java
public class SplitFlux {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).groupBy(i -> i % 2).toStream()
                .forEach(groupedFlux ->
                {
                    System.out.println(groupedFlux.key() == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
                    groupedFlux.toStream().forEach(System.out::println);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, have tried this. but I need to do a repeat() operation on the new Flux. Was not able to perform repeat on GroupedFlux